# Flask pluggable views and login required

Tags: python, flask

I understand how a pluggable view works. What I currently do not understand is how to add a login required to a Class extending View. I currently do this:

```
from flask.views import View

class ShowUsers(View):

    def dispatch_request(self):
        users = User.query.all()
        return render_template('users.html', objects=users)

app.add_url_rule('/users/', view_func=ShowUsers.as_view('show_users'))
```

So how do I force a loginrequired on this class/function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a section in the documentation about [decorating views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/#decorating-views)

Using Flask-Login? If the built in `login_required` decorator isnt suitable for classed based views, then you can write your own - the key is the call to [`unauthorized`](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.LoginManager.unauthorized) on the `LoginManager` instance:

```
from functools import wraps
def user_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated():
            return login_manager.unauthorized()
            # or, if you're not using Flask-Login
            # return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```